# Django Python Server Processing taking too long

Tags: python, django

What could be the reason why cpu processing taking too long?

```
Debug Toolbar Results:
CPU: 3568.22ms (25360.93ms)
SQL: 27 queries in 132.51ms
```

When I tried to ping our server the result is **0.994 ms**

This problem occurs not all the time, sometimes after an hour, everything returns to normal.

Here is the view that handles the request:

```
def pes_to_list(request):
    v = 0
    val = {}
    val['gridlist'] = PesKgmTo.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('to/tolist.html',{'y':v,'page':val},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: GIL possibly? It would be nice to see some code.

Comment: thanks @freakish. I have included the view that handles that request

Comment: Seems more likely to be database contention, if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman. But I am more concern of cpu processing than database database, because it only takes 132.51ms.

Comment: I have observed that it might be the 'python manage.py runserver' problem, because using apache as webserver is working well.

Comment: @rechie Well you don't seem to do anything cpu intensive. And Django's dev server is a pretty solid piece of code. You can even use it in production if the traffic is low. But if you have a rather high traffic, then some bizarre side-effects may occure like that one.